# Importing python packages in Ubuntu server

Tags: python, linux, numpy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, environment

I have a Ubuntu server with restricted access. There I will be hosting my application.
I trying to run Python scripts which were working with the default packages provided by the server. I want to work with numpy and other modules.

As I cannot install or download or do anything, I created a python server in my local machine (WINDOWS) using WSL to emulate the Linux file system and copied the python environment files to the application directory and deployed in cloud.

The problem is no matter in whatever way I try I cannot import numpy (or any module which I copied). I moved all the site-packages to the location of my Python script (As the current script's path will be there in the system path) and tried to import but no luck.
Please help me with crack this in any possible or impossible way.

I am trying to achieve this for the past 6 days and cannot do it.
Please, I have to achieve this at any cost. I have attached my latest structure.

Thank you in advance.

My Folder structure screenshot:
[image: My Folder structure screenshot]

EDIT:

Ok. Let me get this straight. I have a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04) where I am hosting an application. From that application, I am calling python scripts for some machine learning purposes. It is restricted server and I cannot access it. The only way that I found out the Linux distro version is through Java code by calling some terminal commands using "ProcessBuilder". As the server is highly restricted I cannot run any of the Linux commands like echo, set, export, sudo, wget/curl,...etc., Since, python3 is already provided by Linux (by default) I am using that python3 command to call my python scripts (from Java code using "ProcessBuilder") and execute them.

If it is a normal script (if I am using python standard libraries) it is working fine. In one of the scripts I am using "numpy". So, I want to import that module. I am doing the development in a windows environment. So, to emulate the Linux file system for importing packages I created a virtual environment in WSL with same Ubuntu version and installed numpy and then replaced all the symlinks inside those packages with the required files. Then I copied the entire environment and pasted in my resources directory (which is in windows environment) and deployed. No luck.

So, I made a zip file for only "site-packages" folder inside that environment. Then I copied the zip file and pasted in my resources folder and deployed. No luck. The error that I always see is "numpy.core._multiarray_umath". All the articles and in GitHub also tell us to re-install the package. But, I cannot install. I don't have any such access.

How can I import numpy without installation? If there is any work around to achieve this please explain, I will do it. Even if it is harder, complex and time-consuming I am okay with it. I want to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for improving the question with additional details.  But ... now it seems to me that this is a bit "strange".  Why are you attempting to run Python code on this server to which you don't have enough access to even run basic shell commands?  I could be completely wrong, but this seems like a penetration attempt of some sort.

Comment: In hopes that you can convince me otherwise (or perhaps that it is a legitimate penetration attempt for some reason), then my next question would be in regards to , *"created a virtual environment in WSL with same Ubuntu version"*. Do you mean that you created a virtual WSL Ubuntu installation and installed the Python libraries in it?  Or do you mean that you created a Python virtual environment?

Comment: No No No. Not the penetration attempt. I don't have that much knowledge. Actually, the front-end is different server and python (as backend) will be in different server. I want to run the python script in front-end server itself so that I can save 1 server cost.

Comment: Virtual Environment:
I am doing the developing in my machine which is Windows. As windows and Linux are different file systems (server is Linux), I created a python environment locally in WSL in my windows machine. Then copied that environment to the resources folder of the developing application and deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this with:

- a warning to **please check the AUP (acceptable use policy)** of the server you are using, and/or contact the server administrator to make sure you are not violating any rules.
- I can think of quite a few reasons why this *won't* work.  If it doesn't, then there may still be workarounds, but they'll be technically complex.

So if I'm understanding you correctly:

- You have very limited access to the server; basically only the ability to upload (apparently) and run Java code.
- You've also been able to upload Python code and run it through your Java code through `ProcessBuild`.
- You do not have access to log in to a shell, execute arbitrary command other than through `ProcessBuild`, etc.
- Of course, you do not have the ability to install site-packages into the system Python environment.

So ultimately, what you'll probably need to do is something like:

- Create a Python3 virtual environment (which doesn't seem to be what you are actually doing) on WSL.  By a "Python3 virtual environment", I mean [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), which allows you to create a user-level (not system-level) directory with your packages.

  So something like (from inside your project directory):

  ```
  python3 -v venv venv
  source ./venv/bin/activate
  ```

  Your path will be adjusted so that your `python3` and `pip3` commands will be found in the `venv` path.  `pip3 install numpy` will install it into this virtual environment (not the global/system Python).
- Upload that entire `venv` directory to the server.  You seem to have some way of doing this already.
- You're going to have to have some way of running the Bash shell through `ProcessBuilder`.  Since you have the ability to run `python3` through `ProcessBuilder`, I'm kind of assuming that you will be able to do this as well.
- You'll need to (through `ProcessBuild`) activate the virtual environment on the server, `<path_to_project>/venv/bin/activate` and, *in the same Bash shell*  run your code.

  This will look something like:

  ```
  bash -c "source ./venv/bin/activate; python3 main.py"
  ```